# Partial cached values in apollo/graphql

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

Let's say I have a schema like this (pseudocode)

```
query comments: [Comment]
query comment(id: Int!): Comment
```

And I'm fetching comments like this (pseudocode)

```
comments {
 id
 text
}

comment {
 id
 text
 author {
  id
  name
 }
}
```

In my components (pseudo):

```
const comment = useQuery(COMMENT_QUERY, {variables: {id: 1}})
```

My question is this. If I have loaded a feed of `comments`, with the `id` and `text` fields, and then I subsequently load an individual comment, with the added `author` fields, is there a way to get the `useQuery` for the individual comment query to pick up the cached object with the corresponding id from the `comments` query, if it is available? That is to say, the `comments` query should have the `text` field already for a comment with an id that has already been loaded. An additional network request should only be necessary to pick up the `author` fields. It would be lovely if Apollo were clever enough to give me back this partial result immediately, and then the rest of the fields, `author` in my example, when the data become available.

Is that possible with apollo packages/cache, or do I need to write my own `useQuery` wrappers to read the cache directly?

Comment: I may have jumped the gun on asking this question. Is this precisely what `returnPartialData ` is for?

Comment: You need to use a `typePolicy` + `returnPartialData`.